# When doing an update_attributes on my user model with Devise my user gets logged out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, authentication

When I attempt to do an `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])` my user is logged out, or what appears to be logged out.  I get the message, `undefined method 'first_name' for nil:NilClass`. If I go back to my home page I get the log in link.  Why is this happening?  I've read on stackoverflow that I need to include `attr_accessible :admin` but that didn't seem to help at all.

**user.rb update method**

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    if !params[:headshoturl].blank? then
      @user.upload_headshot(params[:headshoturl])
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**Migration File**

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              :null => false, :default => ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, :null => false, :default => ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, :default => 0
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, :default => 0 # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at

      ## Token authenticatable
      # t.string :authentication_token

      # Custom changes
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :user_code

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :users, :email,                :unique => true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         :unique => true
    # add_index :users, :authentication_token, :unique => true
  end
end
```

**routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end

  resources :users
```

Comment: have you made (and run) a migration to allow the user to have a first_name attribute? Have you also made it an accessable attribute in the model?

Comment: `attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :user_code, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :headshot` this is my attr_accessible and yes I've db:migrate'd

Comment: can you post the contents of the migration file, as well as the pertinent methods you are using to update these attributes?

Comment: @ITNinja, I've added a bunch of the code, perhaps my routes file is messing things up? not sure... if anything else would be helpful please let me know.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does `params[:user]` include a `password` and `password_confirmation`?  When you update a user's password, Devise signs them out.  You can prevent this by writing your own `RegistrationsController` and doing `sign_in @user, :bypass => true` after updating your user.

About the first_name error, could you make sure that first_name appears in schema.rb?  I'm thinking maybe you added it to the `DeviseCreateUsers` migration after the migration had already been run.  If that's the case you'd want to create a new migration, create first_name and whatever other fields in it, then do a db:migrate.

Comment: first_name error is just because there is no `current_user`. Could you provide a little more information on the "writing your own RegistrationsController" part? I'm not entirely sure what that would look like or if it already exists where I would edit it.  Do I need to create an entirely new controller or can i edit the one devise uses already? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the wait.  I started making an example Rails app to show how to override the registrations controller but to my surprise, Devise is no longer signing me out after a password change.  (I'm using Devise 3.1.0.) Try updating Devise with ```bundle update devise``` and see if you still have this behavior.